# Weird font spacing and sizing in Visual Studio Code integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code, after a split second the letter spacing and font weight seem to break. A couple of days ago everything was fine. Here is how it looks like compared to my Konsole terminal:

[image]

I looked into the settings and everything looks alright.

Comment: which one is which? what do you expect it to look like? your konsole terminal? can you get a video that show it changing "after a split second"? or a screenshot of how it looks before that split-second change?

Comment: also, there are settings to tune this. `terminal.integrated.lineHeight`, `terminal.integrated.letterSpacing`, `terminal.integrated.fontSize`, `terminal.integrated.fontWeight`, etc.

Comment: @starball It should look like the top one (Konsole). I tried setting `terminal.integrated.letterSpacing` before, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting `Terminal › Integrated: Gpu Acceleration` to `off`. Previously it was set to `auto`.